# Broadcast Message to Routees in a ClusterRouter in Akka

Tags: scala, akka, broadcast, akka-cluster

I'm trying to broadcast a message to all routees in a `ClusterRouter` configuration. I've already tried two alternatives. This one:

```
 val workerRouter = context.actorOf(Props[ClusterRouter].withRouter(
    ClusterRouterConfig(AdaptiveLoadBalancingRouter(metrics), ClusterRouterSettings(
      totalInstances = 100, routeesPath = "/user/slave",
      allowLocalRoutees = true, useRole = None))), name = "slaveRouter")

  context.system.scheduler.schedule(2 seconds, 5 seconds, workerRouter, Broadcast(CapabilityRequest))
```

And this one:

```
 val broadcastRouter = context.actorOf(Props[ClusterRouter].withRouter(
    ClusterRouterConfig(BroadcastRouter(Nil), ClusterRouterSettings(
      totalInstances = 100, routeesPath = "/user/slave",
      allowLocalRoutees = true, useRole = None))), name = "slaveRouter")

  context.system.scheduler.schedule(2 seconds, 5 seconds, broadcastRouter, CapabilityRequest)
```

But for both of them, only one of the `slaves` receive the message. Thoughts?

---

In order to understand why I believe the first attempt should have worked, one has to look at [`AdaptiveLoadBalancingRounter.scala`](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-cluster/src/main/scala/akka/cluster/routing/AdaptiveLoadBalancingRouter.scala#L195), in `AdaptiveLoadBalancingRouterLike` trait, when the `Route` is created:

```
{
  case (sender, message) ⇒
    message match {
      case Broadcast(msg) ⇒ toAll(sender, routeeProvider.routees)
      case msg            ⇒ List(Destination(sender, getNext()))
    }
}
```

Comment: As I asked on the mailing list: can you present proof that your cluster actually has more than one member when you send the messages?

Comment: I can give you the whole code, yes, but then again: (i) a RoundRobinRouter sends messages to every members and (ii) a "manual" broadcast where I iterate through all the members of the network seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, you are using a router that will only send to one routee.  From the docs I've read, this router will use metrics available from the different nodes to select the node that appears to be under the least duress and send a message to the routee that is on that node.  I think the behavior you are seeing for this setup is expected.

With your second example, I did not see anything in the docs about using a `BraodcastRouter` within a clustered environment, so I'm not sure this approach is supported.  Having said that, my guess is that creating the `BraodcastRouter` with an empty list of routees (`Nil`) is what's causing the behavior you are seeing.  I think if you change that to `BroadcastRouter(100)` you might see different behavior.  But again, I don't think (based on the lack of an example in the docs) that using a `BroadcastRouter` is supported (and I could be wrong).

Can you explain a little more into your use case so I can understand why you need a broadcast type router for your cluster?

**Edit**

FWIW, I got things working with the following code.  First, the config:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }

  cluster {
    min-nr-of-members = 2
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551", 
      "akka://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    auto-down = on
  }
}
```

Then, I started up two nodes (one on 2551 the other on 2552) using the following code:

```
object ClusterNode {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    // Override the configuration of the port 
    // when specified as program argument
    if (args.nonEmpty) System.setProperty("akka.remote.netty.port", args(0))


    // Create an Akka system
    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem")
    val clusterListener = system.actorOf(Props(new Actor with ActorLogging {
      def receive = {
        case state: CurrentClusterState =>
          log.info("Current members: {}", state.members)
        case MemberJoined(member) =>
          log.info("Member joined: {}", member)
        case MemberUp(member) =>
          log.info("Member is Up: {}", member)
        case UnreachableMember(member) =>
          log.info("Member detected as unreachable: {}", member)
        case _: ClusterDomainEvent => // ignore

      }
    }), name = "clusterListener")

    Cluster(system).subscribe(clusterListener, classOf[ClusterDomainEvent])    
  }

}

class FooActor extends Actor{

  override def preStart = {
    println("Foo actor started on path: " + context.self.path)
  }

  def receive = {
    case msg => println(context.self.path + " received message: " + msg)
  }
}
```

I then fired up a 3rd "node", my client node, using the following code:

```
object ClusterClient {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem")

    Cluster(system) registerOnMemberUp{
      val router = system.actorOf(Props[FooActor].withRouter(
        ClusterRouterConfig(AdaptiveLoadBalancingRouter(HeapMetricsSelector),
        ClusterRouterSettings(
        totalInstances = 20, maxInstancesPerNode = 10,
        allowLocalRoutees = false))),
        name = "fooRouter")  

     router ! Broadcast("bar")
    }
  }
}
```

When the message was sent, I saw it get received in both server node VMs, 10 actors per VM.

The difference between my router and yours are that I specified no local routees and I swapped `routeesPath` for `maxInstancesPerNode`.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting.  I looked all through the source and I also don't see a good explanation why this does not work.  Do you see 100 slaves get created prior to the broadcast message being sent?

Comment: I'll have to work through your example, since in my case the routeesPath is needed to sort out what routees are eligible. I assume you are running different actors in different VM's, right?

Comment: Yes.  All in all I had 3 total JVMs running (two service nodes, one client node), but everything was local to my mac.  In my example, the actor instances are not deployed until I fire up the client code and start that cluster aware router.  I think things differ when you start up the actor instances yourself on each service node when that service node starts up.

Comment: I'm using a Mac too, soo... Hmmmm... Which version of Akka are you using? 2.1.x or 2.2-Mx ?

Comment: Ok, maybe the fact that I'm using milestone releases of 2.2 explains this :P